Find sub string between two capital words in a text
I would like to get substring between two capitalized words from the string "THIS is the first line in this PARAGRAPH"
I would like the output for this to be "is the first line in this" using c#. I tried using str.All(char.IsUpper) and str.Contains functions to check but with not much luck. Can anyone point in the right direction. I tried researching a bit but I could find answers only to check for one capital character or if a string starts with a capital character.
string str = "THIS is the first line in this PARAGRAPH";


This specific capitalized words or any capitalized word?

Are words always delimited by spaces? Does "I" count as capitalized word? What if there is none, only one or more than one such words? What if two capitalized words are directly adjacent?

@Ralf - any capitalized word with length of capitalized greater than 2

@KlausGütter - Yes words always delimited by spaces and I'm looking for length of capitalized greater than 2 meaning "I" is not considered as capitalized word. I need to display all such repetitions irrespective of none, one or more such words.

Then by example what is the expected result here THIs is THE first LINE in THIS paragraph?  is or first or in or none?

it will be "first" and "in" in this scenario.

To match any 2 or more characters word with all capitalized letters, I would apply simple regular expression pattern:
\b[A-Z]{2,}\b

Explanation:
\b - match word boundary
[A-Z] - match one uppercase letter
{2,} - match at least 2 occurences
With that pattern, we can use Regex.Split method to extract parts between such words. Here's simple example:
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

SplitByCapitalizedWords("THIS is the first line in this PARAGRAPH");
Console.WriteLine("===");
SplitByCapitalizedWords("THIS is THE first LINE in THIS paragraph");

void SplitByCapitalizedWords(string testString)
{
    var parts = Regex.Split(testString, @"\b[A-Z]{2,}\b");

    foreach (var part in parts)
        Console.WriteLine(part);
}

.NET fiddle

Thanks. This is what I was looking for.
